# How to "float left" two divs such that the second div, which contains other divs, resizes correctly

Tags: html, css

I have two divs on a page. The second one contains other divs. I want the second div to reshape when the screen narrows. But instead the whole container moves below the previous div. This fiddle should clarify:
https://jsfiddle.net/gf6zq3pk/7/. I want the green div to stay in position as the screen width is changed and the white boxes to float accordingly.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: dashed;
  border-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu
  <ul>
    <li>Link A</li>
    <li>Link B</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"> Text1 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text2 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text3 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text4 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text5 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text6 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text7 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text8 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3y0jtnf8/

Comment: @banzomaikaka Thanks for the response. Your answer is the simplest and works well.

Comment: It wasn't posted as an answer though so I can't choose it (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use flexbox yet, try this.
Just use `position: absolute;` instead of float to both containers.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 125px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border: dashed;
  border-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  Menu
  <ul>
    <li>Link A</li>
    <li>Link B</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"> Text1 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text2 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text3 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text4 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text5 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text6 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text7 </div>
  <div class="box"> Text8 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, +1 offering an alternative to flex since there were already a few flex answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to flexbox you could add a wrapping container and remove floating properties...

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  border: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  border: dashed;
  border-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  height: 90px;
  /* control the height of the menu here */
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">Menu
    <ul>
      <li>Link A</li>
      <li>Link B</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"> Text1 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text2 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text3 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text4 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text5 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text6 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text7 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text8 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it wasn't quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use flexbox and just nest the left menu in an element so it doesn't "stretch" the height and will be auto height based on content. I would also make the white box container a flex layout, too.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.container {
  border: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  max-width: 550px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu {
  border: dashed;
  border-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: white;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <aside>
    <div class="menu">Menu
      <ul>
        <li>Link A</li>
        <li>Link B</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"> Text1 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text2 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text3 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text4 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text5 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text6 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text7 </div>
    <div class="box"> Text8 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working, he wants them to scale down not drop to the next line. you have to split the flex contents into two separate rows to achieve this.

Comment: @benny Where does OP say 'scale down'?

Comment: @ovokuro "I want the second div to reshape when the screen narrows. But instead the whole container moves below the previous div."

Comment: @benny Exactly... the second div. I don't see a mention of its contents scaling.

Comment: @ovokuro "I want the green div to stay in position as the screen width is changed and the white boxes to float accordingly." maybe the OP can clarify?

Comment: @benny in my example, the green div does scale down and does not move below the previous div. In your code, the green div is below the first div. OP said explicitly that is the **problem** with their current code, they don't want that to happen.

Comment: what did he mean by "reshape" then?

Comment: @benny scale down as the screen resizes, and scale down **beside the first div**, not below it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks for this response. Your understanding of the original question is correct. I did not know about flex before so am looking into it for future use. However I have decided Daniel H gets the answer this time as his is simplest for me to implement.

Comment: @funnyfish cool, you're welcome. It's your question, so I'm not encouraging you to change it or anything, but you should definitely use flexbox over absolute positioning if you can, it's more flexible and doesn't remove those elements from the flow of the page. Try adding html before/after those boxes and you'll see that content stops flowing normally on the page. And definitely look into flex, it makes CSS layouts quite a bit easier.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I will! NB In fact banzomaikaka's solution was even simpler and didn't use absolute positioning. But his answer was posted as a comment to my question so I couldn't choose it. :-)